# C# compiler crashes without an error-message

Tags: c#, .net

```
var xrr = __arglist(Convert.ToUInt32(1), 
                    Convert.ToUInt32(2), 
                    Convert.ToUInt32(3));
```

The above code would make the compiler crash on build.
I would expect the compiler to stop with a meaningful error-message, instead of trying to compile the code.
Could it be a bug in the compiler? If not, how can I solve this error?

Comment: Anything that makes the compiler crash rather than giving an error is a compiler bug.  However, your code is not valid.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour in VS2010

Comment: _"If not, how can I solve this error?"_ Why do you need to use `__arglist` at all? Why can't you use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)?

Comment: I get a compiler error (not a crash) in VS2012.

Comment: I can just feel everyone starting at the page waiting for @Eric Lippert to comment.

Comment: I think this is a bug of compiler and try to post on microsoft support site.Eventhough when I try your code it crashes my vs 2010 too.

Comment: @Rotem, Eric's still busy getting scammed http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/20/um-no/

Comment: @VaibhavParmar: No.   Visual Studio is not the compiler.

Comment: @SLaks its not compiler I know that but I am saying that My compiler crashes in VS 2010.

Comment: I agree with SLaks's answer don't use arglist please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910585/c-sharp-variable-length-args-which-is-better-and-why-arglist-params-array-o

Comment: @VaibhavParmar: If the compiler isn't crashing, you should not say that the compiler is crashing.

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed in VS2013.

Comment: @SLaks I was using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Btw, thanks for crashing Visual Studio for me. I needed to edit the source file with notepad to be able to open Visual Studio 2010 again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a bug in the compiler; the compiler gives a proper error message.
Instead, this is a bug in Visual Studio's editor language service, which causes Visual Studio to crash.

However, your code is illegal anyway; `__arglist(...)` expressions can only be used to call a function that takes an `__arglist`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an issue with Visual Studio, not compiler:

**VS2010**

**System.AccessViolationException**

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**Source**

Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language

**Stack Trace**

```
   at Microsoft.RestrictedUsage.CSharp.Compiler.IDE.CompilerIDEInterop.Compilation_CompileMethod(Handle handle, Handle baseNodeOwner, IntPtr baseNodePtr, Handle& treeHandle)
   at Microsoft.RestrictedUsage.CSharp.Compiler.IDE.IDECompilation.CompileMethod(ParseTreeNode node)
   at Microsoft.RestrictedUsage.CSharp.Compiler.IDE.IDECompilation.CompileMethod(MethodBaseNode method)
   at Microsoft.RestrictedUsage.CSharp.Semantics.SemanticParseTreeVisitor.<>c__DisplayClassc.<DispatchMethodBody>b__a()
   at Microsoft.RestrictedUsage.CSharp.Extensions.ExpressionTreeFinder.get_ExpressionTree()
   at Microsoft.RestrictedUsage.CSharp.Extensions.CompilationExtensions.FindExpressionTree(Compilation compilation, SourceFile sourceFile, ParseTreeNode leafNode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.MemberContainsProvider.MemberContainsItemsSource.GetUniqueLocals(CSharpMemberReference member, ParseTreeNode node, SourceLocation loc, Dictionary`2 dictionary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.MemberContainsProvider.MemberContainsItemsSource.GetUniqueLocals(Dictionary`2 locals)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.MemberContainsProvider.MemberContainsItemsSource.GetMemberChildren()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.MemberContainsProvider.MemberContainsItemsSource.InitializeItemCollection()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.ItemsSource`2.InitializeItems()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.ItemsSource`2.get_Items()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.AggregateItemsSource.InitializeItemCollection()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.ItemsSource`2.InitializeItems()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.ItemsSource`2.get_Items()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.BrowserNavigationEntry.GetTree(String relationship, Func`2 treeActivator)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.Browser.OnSelectedRelationshipChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.Browser.OnCurrentNavigationEntryChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey key, Object value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.Browser.NavigateTo(Object root, IRelationship relationship)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.Browser.NavigateTo(Object root)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.TextViewCreationListener.TextViewSinkManager.TextViewSink.RenderSelectionPopup(Object item, PopupType popupType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.TextViewCreationListener.TextViewSinkManager.TextViewSink.PotentiallyShowCSharpPopup(CSharpTextSelection activeSelection, PopupType popupType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.TextViewCreationListener.TextViewSinkManager.TextViewSink.textView_MouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.OnHoverTimer(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

Comment: I LOVE microsoft exception messages: "This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"